# How to force mongodb to use Guid a _id

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

How do I force MongoDB with MongoDB c# Driver to use Guid as _id?
If I use this code, I always get a FormatException on the Find-Method:
`An error occurred while deserializing the Id property of class UserQuery+TestClass: Cannot deserialize a 'Guid' from BsonType 'ObjectId'.`

```
BsonDefaults.GuidRepresentationMode = GuidRepresentationMode.V3;
BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer<Guid>(new GuidSerializer(GuidRepresentation.Standard));

FilterDefinition<TestClass> filter = """{ Path: "a.b.c.d" }""";
var builder = Builders<TestClass>.Update;
var update = builder.Set("Path", "a.b.c.d").Set("Name", "c.d");
FindOneAndUpdateOptions<TestClass> options = new FindOneAndUpdateOptions<TestClass> { IsUpsert = true };

collNamespace.FindOneAndUpdate<TestClass>(filter, update, options);
var read = collNamespace.Find<TestClass>(filter).FirstOrDefault();
```

Because MongoDB creates an ObjectId for the missing _id.

How do I force MongoDB to really use Guid as _id without setting the _id by myself!!!

Comment: You can't force _MongoDB_ to do it itself as far as I know. From [the docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/document/#the-_id-field) (emphasis added): "_Most MongoDB driver clients will include the _id field and generate an ObjectId before sending the insert operation to MongoDB; however, if the client sends a document without an _id field, **the mongod will add the _id field and generate the ObjectId**._" The client, either through a library or manually, can supply (almost) any value/type for that field, but that doesn't seem like what you're looking for